# Shiro: Session already invalidated

Tags: java, session-state, shiro

I am using Apache Shiro in a web-application. The login and authentication check works well, but I have a problem to implement a logout / re-login mechanism: The logout is done in a servlet:

```
    private void logout(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
            log.debug("do logout");
            Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
            subject.logout();
            resp.sendRedirect("end.html");
    }
```

But after a logout and re-login I get the following error:

```
org.apache.shiro.session.InvalidSessionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
  getAttribute: Session already invalidated
  at org.apache.shiro.web.session.HttpServletSession.removeAttribute(HttpServletSession.java:167)
at org.apache.shiro.session.ProxiedSession.removeAttribute(ProxiedSession.java:135)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.clearRunAsIdentities(DelegatingSubject.java:424)
at org.apache.shiro.subject.support.DelegatingSubject.login(DelegatingSubject.java:246)
```

The login is done in the following way (in a method of a UI component, I use ZK as UI framework):

```
  private void tryLogin(UsernamePasswordToken token) {
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        try {
              subject.login(token);
              ...
```

I do not understand the exception as the logout from shiro invalidates the session and the re-login should access a new session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will occur in Shiro before version 1.2 if someone (or something else) invalidates the session before `Subject.logout()` is invoked (e.g. `httpSession.invalidate()` and then `subject.logout()`).

This has been raised as a bug in [SHIRO-298](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SHIRO-298) and it has already been resolved in 1.2.0-SNAPSHOT builds.  You can use one of the current snapshot builds or use Shiro 1.2.0 when it is released.

Comment: Hi, I'm using shiro version `1.2.4`, still getting the same issue ` getAttribute: Session already invalidated` after a logout and re-login. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

it looks like your UI framework is not regenerating the session after logout.
You can try to force a new the session calling subject.getSession() just before the login call. Something like this:

```
private void tryLogin(UsernamePasswordToken token) {
        Subject subject = SecurityUtils.getSubject();
        Session session = subject.getSession();
        try {
              subject.login(token);
```